# Weierstrass elliptic funcion in Laurent series form

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, number-theory, elliptic-functions

Could anyone please help me to figure out how
$$f_0(z) = \wp(\log z; i\pi, \log \rho)$$
where $\wp$ denotes the Weierstrass elliptic function and $i \pi$ and $\log \rho$ are its half periods.
 $$  f_0(z) = \displaystyle  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \rho^{2n}z^{-n}}{1-\rho^{2n}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n z^{n}}{1-\rho^{2n}}.  $$

Can $\log z$ have Laurent expansion at the origin?

Z. Nehari and B. Schwarz, [On the coefficients of univalent Laurent series](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1954-0061172-6), Proc. Amer.  Math. Soc., 5, 1954, 212 - 217 (page 214).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\wp_{\tau}(z) = \frac1{z^2} + \sum_{(n,m) \ne (0,0)}\frac1{(z+n\tau+m)^2}-\frac1{(n\tau+m)^2}$$ is $1$ periodic and analytic on $\Im(z) \in (0,|\Im(\tau)|)$ so it has a Fourier series valid for $\Im(z) \in (0,|\Im(\tau)|)$ which is a Laurent series for $\wp_{\tau}(\frac{\log u}{2i\pi})$ valid for $|e^{2i \pi u}| \in (1,e^{|\Im(\tau)|})$

The Fourier coefficients are found from the pole expansion of inverse of trigonometric functions. For $\Im(z) > 0$ $$\sum_{m}\frac{1}{(z+m)^2}= \frac{d}{dz} \frac1{1-e^{2i \pi z}}= \sum_{k \ge 0} (2i\pi k) e^{2 i \pi  kz}$$
For $\Im(z) < 0$ $$\sum_{m}\frac{1}{(z+m)^2}= \frac{d}{dz} \frac1{1-e^{2i \pi z}}= \sum_{k \ge 1} (-2i\pi k) e^{-2 i \pi  kz}$$

Comment: What is $\tau$ here. In books $$\wp(z) = \frac{1}{z^2} + \sum_{\omega \neq 0}\left(\frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2} - \frac{1}{\omega^2}\right)$$  where $\omega = m \omega_1 + n \omega_2$ , $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are the periods. Here $\omega = m i\pi + n\log \rho$, and  Laurent series for $\wp(z)$ is $$\wp(z) = \frac{1}{z^2} + a_1 z^2 + a_2 z^4 +... $$, odd powers of $z$ vanished, then how in the paper they have negative powers of $z$.

Comment: $\omega_1= 1,\tau = \omega_2$. Your formula is not a Laurent expansion in $z$ but a Fourier series in $z$ thus a Laurent expansion in $e^{2i \pi z}$